# Data refresh error using VBA code to refresh Excel connection

Tags: excel, connection, vba7

I created a connection in Excel using SQL query, and I have a dynamic query in my Excel cell.  This will be dynamic and will be updated based on the slicer options I created.

I want to run the query based on the dynamic query refers from Excel cell.

Below is the VBA code to refer the query and refresh the connection to run.

I get

> run-time error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

The code runs till the line "Sheet1.Select", but it throws error while executing the yellow highlighted line.
[image]

CodeString = picks the updated query from Sheet2.Range("A1")

Below is the code from Sheet2, this is dynamic, will be changed as required.
[image]